# MySQL Join Syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm having problems understanding the MYSQL join syntax. I can't seem to manipulate it for my purpose. I have had to use work arounds for months which have resulted in extra queries just for retrieving one extra column.

Scenario: I have two tables..

***Table.Stories*** - containing stories and the user ID of which whom added it.

id, story, userid

***Table.Users*** - containing user details and the users ID

id, username

I'd like to retrieve the stories table including the users id along with a new column (which is generated on the fly I guess) called username which holds the corresponding username from ***Table.Users***.

I'm guessing I would use a mix of the **AS** and **LEFT JOIN** syntax. But I really don't know anymore..

Comment: Also please provide the queries you tried

Comment: Most of my attempts have resulted in errors. The ones which have worked have combined the two tables giving me a bunch of 'unnecessary columns'. I only want a new username column from Table.Users.

Comment: Attempts have looked somewhat similar to this. 

SELECT *  FROM `stories` LEFT JOIN users ON stories.id = siteusers.id AS username

Excuse my laughable syntax.

Comment: Thank you all kind sirs. You have all surprised me by your timely responses. Peace be on you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id, s.story, s.userid, u.username FROM stories AS s INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.userid=u.id
```

Explanation to follow.

Comment: Assuming that there is a user for each story, there is no need for a LEFT JOIN. An INNER JOIN requires that there is a row in the tables on each "side" of the JOIN, while a LEFT JOIN just returns NULL values for each column in the second table, if there is no row matching the ON criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Following query will help you:

```
SELECT s.story, u.username FROM Stories s 
LEFT JOIN Users u ON (u.id=s.userid)
```

It returns value of `story` field of a story record and `username` of corresponding user.

Comment: Yes, but what is the problem with null?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT s.id, s.story, u.username
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN users u
ON u.id = s.userid
```

This basically says: "Give me the story id, story name, and the user from the Stories table, looking up the username from the Users table where the Users table ID matches the Stories table's userid."♦

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.*, COALESCE(u.username, 'unknown') AS username
FROM Table.Stores st
LEFT JOIN Table.Users u ON st.userid = u.id
```

Simple really; make sure you have an index on id within Table.users.  The COALESCE function returns the first argument which isn't null so you can define the value for a story where no user if found.

If you're only interested in stories that have a corresponding user, then use

```
SELECT st.*, u.username
FROM Table.Stores st
JOIN Table.Users u ON st.userid = u.id
```

The inner join is implicit here and doesn't need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

select stories.*, Users.username from stories inner join Users On Stories.userid = Users.id

OR

select * from stories inner join Users using(userID) (if you keep consistent ID columns)

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a one-to-one relation, i.e. each story always has a user, then you should use an inner join:

```
select t.id, t.story, t.userid, u.username
from Table.Stories t
inner join Table.Users u on u.id = t.userid
```

If the userid field can be null, indicating that a story can have a user or not, you should use a left join:

```
select t.id, t.story, t.userid, u.username
from Table.Stories t
left join Table.Users u on u.id = t.userid
```

For the story records where there is no user, the username field will be returned as null.